# How to know the place of error in my RN code with RN 0.46

Tags: react-native

Before RN 0.46, if there is a error in my RN code.
RN will tell me whick js file, which line and column is wrong on the mobile screen.

But with RN 0.46, it simply say "The development server returned response error code: 500." and leave developer high and dry...

This is very unfriendly to developer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `create-react-native-app` or `react-native init`?

If you are using `create-react-native-app` actually it the log will appear in your terminal (that you use for `yarn start` or `npm start`).

If you are using `react-native init`, I used to use `react-native log-android` (or for ios use `react-native log-ios`).

Or maybe you will try another debugging method listed in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

Comment: I used create-react-native-app to creat RN project. the log appeared in my terminal is "Failed building JavaScript bundle".

Comment: You can easily recreate this bug by require a nonexist file in a simple RN project. For example: let aPic = require('./notexist.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `console.log()` to get the response and find the error message.